# How to use active-reactive parameters when using 'Build job' in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Assume there are two jenkins jobs job A and job B.
Both jobs contain Active-reactive parameters of checkbox choice type, job A is triggered by user by selecting parameters, now what is the syntax for triggering job B inside the pipeline of job A with the same choices chosen when triggering job A.

I know the syntax for triggering another job with string parameters
   `build job: 'RunArtInTest', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'systemname', value: systemname]]` how do I do the same for active-reactive choice parameters